# Running an executable as a server-side "script"

Tags: web-services, ubuntu

I've been currently using PHP on Apache (on Ubuntu) to do dynamic server-side stuff, but is it possible to run a compiled C program as the intermediary? If so, how? I know it's probably not that useful anyway, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CGI with any language, here's [an example for C](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html). CGI is slow and not very flexible though, so you should avoid it. If you really need to write a web application in C, try something more robust like [OKWS](http://www.okws.org/doku.php?id=okws).

That said, writing a web application in C has very little advantages for most cases. Consider it only if your application is CPU bound.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of PHP's [system](http://au.php.net/system), [exec](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [shell_exec](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to run a script from php